# Rolling a fair die 10 times, what is the probability of rolling exactly one '1' AND exactly one '2'?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

So in other words, if X denotes the number of 1's rolled in 10 attempts, and Y denotes the number of 2's rolled in 10 attempts, what is the probability that X=Y=1?

I know the probability of rolling any particular number exactly once in 10 attempts is

10C1 * (1/6) * (5/6)^9

And I was able to calculate in an earlier problem the probability that X=Y=0 (I got (4/6)^10).

But I am unsure how to calculate this when we need two numbers to be rolled exactly once.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is perfectly clear what OP is asking.

Comment: The binomial distribution can only be used if we have two events. But here we have $3$ : one, two something else. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. You need a multinomial distribution.

Comment: @trueblueanil This bot has a quite poor performance in distinguishing between unclear and contextless question from perfectly fine questions. Not the only clear failure.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting a $1$ and $2$ on $2$ rolls is $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}$

There are $10 \times 9 = 90$ ways to choose the $2$ positions where $1$ and $2$ will be rolled out of the $10$ rolls.

The probability of getting a $3, 4, 5$ or $6$ on all of the other $8$ rolls is $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{8} = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8}$.

The final probability hence is

$$90 \times \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}\times \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8} = \boxed{\frac{640}{6561}}$$